# Oracle.dataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory error for a webService on VS

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working on a C# WebService on Visual Studio 2012 which use data from an oracle Database and convert them with the EntityManager of visual studio.

On my computer it works fine, but as soon as I publish it on a server IIS, I got this error :

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The store provider
>   factory type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' does not
>   implement the IServiceProvider interface. Use a store provider that
>   implements this interface.

It happens when I try to get a connection on my database with the Entity framework and I don't know how to look at this problem in order to fix it.

DATA

I work with Oracle.DataAccess v 4.112.3 and .NETFramework 4.5

this is part of my web.config with the connection string

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="EntitiesCCMX" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelCCMX.csdl|res://*/ModelCCMX.ssdl|res://*/ModelCCMX.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=CCMX;password=rhcs;persist security info=True;user id=CCMX&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  <add name="HastusEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelHASTUS.csdl|res://*/ModelHASTUS.ssdl|res://*/ModelHASTUS.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=GIRO2010.WORLD;password=hastus2010;user id=HASTUS2010&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

What I already did :

- I allowed 32bit application on the server
- I reinstalled oracle on my computer and on the server
- I try to send the oracle.DataAccess.dll on the server
- I configured the oranet which redirect on my database

If you need anything more, please ask. I am really stuck with this one...

EDIT :

Managed to "fix" it but I'm not sure why, I will post a response will all the things I done if it keep working for a day or two.

Anyways, for short, 
- I add 8 dll (oci, ociw32, Oracle.DataAccess, oraocci11, oraocciei11, oraocciocu11, OraOps11w, System.Data.OracleClient)
- I changed this line in Machine.Config (Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config)

```
    <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

by this line (Version = 4.112.3.0)

```
   <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

And I installed Visual Studio professional 2012 on the server (And I think that this instalation moved some repertory or some paths)

I will be back when I"m sure.

EDIT2

Didn't work anymore without touching at anything. But it's another error now.

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is stated at oracle's web site 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html
It's the oracle version, you need newer one. 
The last error it's just a connection error. try to tnsping the database from the server, if it works check your connection string.

Comment: Think about including essential parts from the link here.